# Pandas dataframe use column names in train data to select same column names in test data

Tags: pandas

I am looking for a way to automatically change feature position `train2.iloc[:,2]` (code only gives feature position) to the feature name as my test data needs these same features for prediction e.g:

```
columns = ['m2','m4','m12','m14'].
```

My problem is that the features selected after training train data changes depending on param_grid used.

How can I change feature position to feature name  in train data and then use these to select same feature names in my test data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position (i.e. 2 in your example) you can just index into the column list. i.e. train_df.columns[2] , you could then use that select the column in your test set i.e. test_df[train_df.columns[2]]

Comment: Thank you for your response..problem is that I won't know which columns have been selected, I just want whatever columns have been selected in train data to be automatically selected also in test data. Columns selected in train data changes all the time.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code? And an example of the returned values? It sounds like you are getting a list of column indices, which makes it hard to understand the actual issue.

Comment: OK. ..the code uses GridSearchCV to determine the important features to keep

Comment: That's still not a lot to go on but hopefully this helps. If you want to perform feature selection prior to fitting you can set up a pipeline per the bottom of:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

Alternatively you can transform training and test data based on the best parameters of GridSearchCV using the transform method of the GridSearchCV class, call that on your test data to select just the best parameters
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.transform

Comment: Sorry tvashtar, my phone was playing up

Comment: Essentially, I use GridSearchCV to select the important features to keep from my training data then use these same feature names to select same features in the test data for prediction. Currently I do col = features_to_keep....this gives just feature positions then test_new = pd.DataFrame(test,columns=col). This returns NaN as it is expecting feature names and not feature position. I want the features_to_keep to be feature names and not position

Comment: Just had an idea...convert the feature names in test to position then that should solve my problem...test_new.columns = arange(0,len(test_new.columns)). What do you think?

Comment: test_new.columns = range(0,len(test_new.columns)) has solved my problem. Thank you for your help tvashtar

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Best of luck.